# How to make the headphones hear the microphone in C# (not streaming)

Tags: c#, windows, audio

Windows Sound mixer/settings can set the microphone to play over the speakers.  I'm looking for a way to do that through C#.  I'm assuming there is a DLL reference or .NET call that might be able to.

Everything I've been finding invariably goes back to streaming, which I don't want to do.  Unless that's whats actually happening under the hood when changing the audio settings in windows.

If it helps, I'm using C# 3.5 (Unity App) and running on Windows 10 latest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Core Audio APIs [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316602(v=vs.85).aspx)

For implementation you can refer 
https://blog.sverrirs.com/2016/02/windows-coreaudio-api-in-c.html